# Return value for a specific key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object with numbers as keys and image paths as values. I am getting numbers from a combination of selected radio buttons. Such as 1111 or 2111 if the first radio buttons in each group are all selected or the second radio then all first. I want to search the object for a key of 1111 then if it exists, return its value, which would be an image path. I can successfully find if the object has a matching key, but how do I return the value for that key only? In the case of 1111 I would need to return "my/image/path1". Here is what I have so far:

```
    var array = [];
var imgs = {
    1111: "my/image/path1",
    2111: "my/image/path2",
    1211: "my/image/path3",
    1311: "my/image/path4"
}

$(':radio').change(function() {
    $(":radio:checked").each(function(i, e)  {
    array[i] = $(this).val();
    });
        var total = 0;
        $.each(array,function() {
            total += this;
        });
        matchKey = parseInt(total, 10);
         // here is where I'm stuck
        if (imgs contains the key matchKey)) {
            console.log(value for matchKey);
        }

});
```

Comment: Use bracket notation: `if (imgs[matchKey]) {...}`.

Comment: are the keys and value unique to each radio button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use square-bracket notation

```
if (imgs[matchKey]) {
    console.log(imgs[matchKey]);
}
```

Note: This assumes none of your *values* will ever be falsey (eg, `0`, a blank string, `false` etc). Which I think is fine, as you said your values are always non-empty paths. But the warning stands. If your values could legitimately be falsy, check @Florian answer.

Comment: This will return false when `matchKey == 0`.

Comment: @JacquesMarais - which is great, as there was no property of the object with key `0`. Works as expected!

Comment: This works, thanks. So object[key] always returns the keys value?

Comment: @jfoutch yes, `myobject.mykey` is equivalent to `myobject["mykey"]`

Comment: I wish I had known that and I would never have needed to post the question ha! Learn something everyday. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can use plain javascript:

```
if (typeof imgs[matchKey] !== "undefined") { // Check if the key exists
    var value = imgs[matchKey];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys(imgs) to retrieve an array of just the keys, and then perform a simple test to see if the key you're looking for is contained in the array:

```
if (Object.keys(imgs).indexOf('1111') > -1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the key-value pair by iterating through each element in array imgs using `$.each`

```
var imgs = {
    1111: "my/image/path1",
    2111: "my/image/path2",
    1211: "my/image/path3",
    1311: "my/image/path4"
}


$.each(imgs,function(key,value)
{
    if(key === 1111)
     return value; // This would give you the path "my/image/path1"

});
```